# Create formula in jopendocument

Tags: java, formulas, jopendocument

How can I create a formula in jopendocument which is evaluated, if the file is opened in a spread sheet application like oocalc?

I want to fill in value and set up formulas that will help the user of the spreadsheet and enables him to dig into the values.